# Как изменить опции поля формы в Subscriber

Tags: php, symfony2

В общем есть `FormType`, где есть поле. При создании это поле должно быть обязательным, при редактировании не обязательным. `Subscriber` на этот `type`.

Поле в `FormType`

```
 ->add("logo", FileType::class, [
                "label"    => "Health Plans logo",
                "mapped"   => true,
                "required" => true
            ])
```

В `postSetData` забираю форму: 
`$form->get('config')->get('logo')` - это `FormType` в `FormType` как видно. 
Так я забираю нужно мне поле.

Как мне установить полю `mapped` полученого объекта значение `false` ?

Comment: После правки вопроса поменялась его суть =) Subscriber на этот type смешно=)

Comment: Лучше бы оставили вопрос без правок сейчас там написана какая то хрень которую я бы не понял. В общем в Subscriber нужно изменить mapped филда. Есть метод getConfig()->getMapped() но set  я не нашёл

Comment: Лучше бы, вы сами написали вопрос с запятыми и как можно понятнее. И да, зачем возмущаться, возьмите и отредактируйте вопрос как нужно, чтобы суть стала правильной

Comment: Я просто заскриншотил до и после =)

Answer (score 1):

1. На заметку: опция `required` нужна лишь чтобы в HTML вставить аттрибут `required` и ещё парочки плюшек. Данная опция никак не связана с валидацией  [источник](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required)
2. Для решения вашей проблемы в её текущем состоянии вы можете воспользоваться передаваемой опцией `data`, например

   ```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       /** @var MyEntity $data */
       $data = $options['data'];
       // ...
       ->add(
           "logo", 
           FileType::class, 
           [
               "label"    => "Health Plans logo",
               "mapped"   => true,
               // данных нет или у них отсутствует id (т.е. ещё не создана)
               "required" => $data === null || empty($data->getId())
           ]
       )
   ```